# Notepad++ Find and Replace Expert Suggestion

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors

I need help with Find and Replace in Notepad++.

Example:

$250
'Hello 1'
Take '____'

$500
'Hello 2'
Take '____'

$1000
'Hello 3'
Take '____'

Imagine there are thousands of these entries going up to 'Hello 9999'.

I want to replace '____' with a number without changing 'Hello 1' or 'Hello 2'.

I would like the outcome to be:

$250
'Hello 1'
Take '250'

$500
'Hello 2'
Take '500'

$1000
'Hello 3'
Take '1000'

How can I go about doing this? I would expect using a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Tick the regular expression checkbox and use:

Search:

```
\$(.*?) (.*?) Take '(.*?)'
```

Replace:

```
\$$1 $2 Take '$1'
```

---

This will search for a line who basically looks like this:

```
$anything anything Take 'anything'
```

.*? means any character except a new line in regular expressions.
Wrapping parenthesis around a capture group such as .*? will store the content of it in a variable which is $n where n is the n-th group.

So after the search we will have three variables:
$1 = 250
$2 = 'Hello 1'
$3 = ___

With the replace, we replace the actual whole line with
\$ (escaping the dollar sign makes it a litteral $ and not a variable).
The whole line is replaced by $$1 $2 '$1'
As you can see we use again the $1 variable who is the first capturing group.

---

I'm quite new on SO, so sorry if my explanations aren't that great.

Comment: I don't quite understand, would you mind explaining how this method works? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, sorry. I should have explained in my original post. I'll update it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how would I apply this solution to a multi line document? I have an example here: http://hastebin.com/efohesonis.sm

Where 'Price ' will be duplicated to 'Coins:____' and 'give:material:28' will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the Notepad++ syntax, having selected the "Regular Expression" radio button at the bottom of the Find/Replace dialog:

```
Find:  (\$(\d+).*Take\s+').*(')
Replace:  \1\2\3
```

Explanation:

Parenthesis group variables in order by counting from left to right:

```
(\$(\d+).*Take\s+').*(')
|--------1--------|
   |-2-|             |3|
```

\$  : means find dollar sign

\d+ : means find digits, "+" at the end means one or more (i.e. MUST be at least one digit).

.*  : "." means ANY character, and "*" means one or more.

Take : is just specifically the word Text.

\s+ : means space characters, and "+" means one or more.

...

Now, because everything is grouped EXCEPT the last characters in the single quotes, then:

```
\1\2\3
```

Just puts the first and third parenthesis, with the second in between (where the second parenthesis is the dollar value).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how would I apply this solution to a multi line document? I have an example here: http://hastebin.com/efohesonis.sm

Where 'Price ' will be duplicated to 'Coins:____' and 'give:material:28' will be saved.

Comment: That example looks like yaml.  Do you have any scripting ability?  Maybe use Python/Perl/Ruby, or even a crude sed script, would give you more power and flexibility than regex in Notepad++.  
...  
However, if you must use Notepad++ regex, there is a checkbox that should read something like ". matches newline".  Select this checkbox, so multiline matches can be performed.  Then update the regex to match up to "Coins:" with some other modifiers, probably "?" to make the regex non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

First turn on Regular expressions

[image: Notepad++ Settings to turn on Regular Expressions]

https://regex101.com/r/aW4gG2/2

Find: `(\$\d+)(.*Take ')(.*)(')`
Replace: `\1\2\1\4`

## Capture

There are four groups to this Expression

Input: `$250 'Hello 1' Take '____'`

**Group 1**
`(\$d+)` = `$250` - this says start with a $ (escaped to be literal) then digits (`\d`) 1 or more so it stops at the last digit whether it's 3 or 15. In your example they were at the start of the line but I don't assume that. If however they DO start the line then you might want to add a `^` making it `^(\Sd+)`

**Group 2**
`(.*Take ')` =  `'Hello 1' Take '` - the expression says `.*` which means any character any number of times so it take everything until it sees `Take` and then it takes the `Take '` because i wrote that out and stops there.

**Group 3**
`(.*)` =  - `____` this takes the internal space basically it takes anything 0 or more times. In this case it's all underscores but written it would grab everything and anything you have there. It would grab everything to the end of the lines except I have something following which tells it when to stop

**Group 4**
`(')` =  - `'` this tells group 3 to stop at the `'` mark. it also captures the `'` mark in it's own group for rearranging.

## Substitution

`\1\2\1\4`

Groups are numbered from their open parenthesis but in this case everything is linear with no nesting so it's pretty obvious. `\1\2\3\4` would leave everything the way it is. But we want to replace the third group with the first group so.... `\1\2\1\4` does the trick. One of the key points here was making sure we captured that fourth group to replace it at the end. Beyond that nothing too tricky.

## Execution

So just set that up in your find replace and then hit replace all and that should fix you up.

## Edit

I noticed you wanted to strip the $ in your replacement so you need to make some minor changes to my initial suggestions though it's basically the same.

Input: `$250 'Hello 1' Take '____'`

Find: `(\$)(\d+)(.*Take ')(.*)(')`
Replace: `\1\2\3\2\5`